# How to use pnpm / supi programmatically to install packages?

Tags: pnpm

I want to use pnpm or supi programmatically inside nodejs to install packages from a private repository into a specific directory.
Is there any documentation on how to accomplish this?

I am kind of (ab)using the system as these packages do not contain code but rather results of some computation, but I don't think that it matters.

Currently I am using npm by calling

```
exec(`npm install ${pkgName} --registry ${registry}`, {cwd: destDir}, (err, stdout, stderr) => {...});
```

I would like to use pnpm for this but without using exec.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can use [this lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@pnpm/exec) but it will use exec under the hood. Or you can use supi but it is not perfectly documented. You'll need to pass a store controller to it. Maybe you can check how it is done in the [tests](https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/blob/master/packages/supi/test/utils/testDefaults.ts) or in [pnpm](https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/tree/master/packages/pnpm)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. If I were to use your library, what is the best way to supply an auth token for the private package repo?

Comment: The supi library accept a rawNpmConfig property. This property is basically what a .npmrc would contain. So you use the same format to pass auth tokens. You can see that in supi's tests: https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/blob/93a5c285c2e608b9725a9be783df280526fffefa/packages/supi/test/install/auth.ts#L28-L37